# OSGeo4W updating is failing - OpenCL.dll was not found

Tags: qgis-3, osgeo4w, windows-10

Windows 10. I've not used my 3 installations of QGIS for 6 weeks maybe. I updated them via OSGeo4w but I get the error "The code execution cannot proceed because OpenCL.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem".
[image]

OSGeo4w gives me the error

> Package: qgis-common qgis-common.bat exit code -1073741515.
> Package: qgis-ltr-common qgis-ltr-common.bat exit code -1073741515

Attempting to open any of the QGIS installations gives me the error
[image]

Reinstalling the programmes produces the same errors. Can anyone help please?

Comment: This may well be a Windows 10 issue that is not allowing correct installation/opening of the OSGeo4W programmes?

Comment: OpenCL is used for parallel processing for example in gdal. OSGeo4W comes wirh a opencl.dll and tries to install it through the qgis installation process. Did you install QGis with administrator privileges?

Comment: I've tried that 2 times, same errors occur. I have 4 QGIS installations as part of the process. I get the error 'The code execution cannot proceed because OpenCL.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem' for each of the 4 installations - 4 error windows.

Comment: Tried to uninstall (not reinstall) all QGIS versions and I received the same error messages. They seem to be NOT uninstalled.

Comment: How can you have errors after uninstalling qgis? And what do you mean with having 4 Installations? Which Installer do you use? Where has QGIS been installed? There should be a directory: C:\OSGeo4W or OSGeo4w64. Inside is a folder named bin and it should contain opencl.dll. This will be copied to the Windows system directory when installing qgis. I guess your error with qgis-common.bat rised during the installation? I think you should investigate, why this happens. The bat file is located under osgeo4w\etc\postinstall and can run it from a OSGeo Command Shell.

Comment: Installation/uninstallation/upgrading - all now give error messages. Yes,  C:\OSGeo4W is my directory. My installations are QGIS 2.18, 3.4, 3.8 and 3.9. There is no opencl.dll file in my bin directory. I have no idea how to "run it from a OSGeo Command Shell".

Comment: Why do you need all these versions? Try to uninstall and use just qgis-ltr (3.4). If this does not work, go and delete all files from that directory and from the temporary cache folder. I think this should be under %Temp%\http.something.cryptic. May be that a package download failed and causes trouble. The osgeo4w Shell is cmd Window you'll find it in the Windows start menu.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue while installing QGIS 3.34 via OSGeo4W after a fresh Windows 10 installation. After trying for hours, I was able to solve the problem by applying the following:

- Uninstall QGIS via OSGeo4W Setup.
- Rename existing `OpenCL.dll` in `c:\Windows\System32`, Or delete... because OSGeo installation adds `opencl.dll` if not exists.
- Run QSGeo Setup as Administrator.

It is also possible that you get the same error due to a different reason.